# Is it safe to remove swapfile from /etc/fstab?

Tags: 18.04, mount, swap, fstab

I have 64GB RAM and disabled `swap`. When I arrange my HDDs to mount in `/etc/fstab`, I wonder if it is still necessary to keep this line

```
/swapfile                       none            swap    sw              0       0
```

in `/etc/fstab`?

Comment: How did you disable it?

Comment: @Pilot6 `swapoff -a`

Comment: This is a temporary off till next reboot,

Comment: @Pilot6 but I have no swap even after rebooting. The system monitor shows "Swap not available". Do you mean removing the swap entry from `/etc/fstab` is indeed a key step to disable swap?

Comment: That's correct. Maybe swapoff is persistent, I always though it wasn't. Anyway you can remove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not using swap, you can remove it from fstab and delete `/swapfile`.

There is nothing in this operation that may be called "unsafe".

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I just thought maybe, Ubuntu needs to check `/swapfile` in `/etc/fstab`.

Comment: It checks for swapfile if it is declared in fstab.

Comment: But _how to know_ if one is "not using swap"?

Comment: Run `swapon -s` and see.